# Turning an existing application into a service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have seen the documentation on Services and am trying to turn an existing application into a service. I have seen varying answers on how difficult this is. Which functions must you override to turn existing code into a service?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write a service that will be able to do what you need to do (which you didn't state), not convert an application to a service.  Services don't have interfaces as such, so I'm having a difficult time seeing how any application would live as a service.